# Android Drive API OAuth BAD_AUTHENTICATION

Tags: java, android, oauth, google-drive-api

I'm having a problem with the Google Drive REST v3 android API. The OAuth token is getting a BAD_AUTHENTICATION result. Here's the connection code I'm using. It can also be noted that the OAuth consent screen is not showing up, and after a short period of time, I get the BAD_AUTHENTICATION result. Am I required to manually pass a refresh token to the server or something?

```
// Gather credentials
credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES)).setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Roblu", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String accountName = settings.getString("accountName", "");
credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);

// Start Google services
HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
service = new com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName("Roblu").build();
```

Here's the result code:

```
08-15 14:11:27.621 4929-15182/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account: <ELLIDED:-238957088>, App: com.google.android.gms, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games
                                    dkq: Long live credential not available.
                                        at dkr.a(:com.google.android.gms:3101)
                                        at dje.a(:com.google.android.gms:397)
                                        at djd.a(:com.google.android.gms:31369)
                                        at djd.a(:com.google.android.gms:313)
                                        at elb.a(:com.google.android.gms:1201)
                                        at ela.a(:com.google.android.gms:530)
                                        at ela.a(:com.google.android.gms:196)
                                        at dfw.a(:com.google.android.gms:320)
                                        at dfw.a(:com.google.android.gms:210)
                                        at dgf.a(:com.google.android.gms:1498)
                                        at dge.a(:com.google.android.gms:909)
                                        at dge.e(:com.google.android.gms:523)
                                        at dgd.a(:com.google.android.gms:37)
                                        at dhm.getAuthToken(:com.google.android.gms:178)
                                        at android.accounts.AbstractAccountAuthenticator$Transport.getAuthToken(AbstractAccountAuthenticator.java:214)
                                        at android.accounts.IAccountAuthenticator$Stub.onTransact(IAccountAuthenticator.java:113)
                                        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based from this [thread](https://github.com/google/gdata-objectivec-client/issues/16), you're getting an error maybe because the user's account is attached to both a hosted account and a Google account, and probably it has different passwords for each The authentication servers currently do not handle this well. Follow this [Connecting to Google Drive with Google APIs Client Library for Java](http://www.techsfo.com/blog/2014/04/android-app-connecting-to-google-drive-with-google-apis-client-library-for-java-part-3/) tutorial.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   ...
   // Google Accounts using OAuth2
   m_credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE));

   m_client = new com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Builder(
            m_transport, m_jsonFactory, m_credential).setApplicationName("AppName/1.0")
            .build();
   ...
}
```

You can also check on these related issues:

- [Bad Authentication Error Rails connecting to google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070336/bad-authentication-error-rails-connecting-to-google-drive)
- [Google Drive: 403 Authentication failed](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-bootstrap/issues/11)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Okay well your fix didn't actually work, I still upvoted your answer but my stack account isn't high enough or something so it won't display publicly yet..